# Result of math.log in Python pandas DataFrame is interger

Tags: python, pandas, math

I have a DataFrame, all values are integer

```
        Millage  UsedMonth  PowerPS
1        261500        269      101
3        320000        211      125
8        230000        253      101
9        227990        255      125
13       256000        240      125
14       153000        242      150
17       142500        215      101
19       220000        268      125
21       202704        260      101
22       350000        246      101
25       331000        230      125
26       250000        226      125
```

And I would like to calculate log(Millage)
SO I used code

```
x_trans=copy.deepcopy(x)
x_trans=x_trans.reset_index(drop=True)
x_trans.astype(float)

import math
for n in range(0,len(x_trans.Millage)):
    x_trans.Millage[n]=math.log(x_trans.Millage[n])
x_trans.UsedMonth[n]=math.log(x_trans.UsedMonth[n])
```

I got all interger values

```
    Millage UsedMonth   PowerPS
0   12  5   101
1   12  5   125
2   12  5   101
3   12  5   125
4   12  5   125
5   11  5   150
```

It's python 3, Jupyter notebook
I tried math.log(100)
And get 4.605170185988092

I think the reason could be DataFrame data type. 
How could I get the log() result as float
Thanks

Comment: Instead of mutating an existing integer column, create a new column using `numpy.log` (without a loop) and append/replace with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to simply do

```
x_trans['Millage'] = np.log(x_trans['Millage'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Conversion to `astype(float)` is not an in-place operation. Assign back to your dataframe and you will find your log series will be of type `float`:

```
x_trans = x_trans.astype(float)
```

But, in this case, `math.log` is inefficient. Instead, you can use vectorised functionality via NumPy:

```
x_trans['Millage'] = np.log(x_trans['Millage'])
x_trans['UsedMonth'] = np.log(x_trans['UsedMonth'])
```

With this solution, you do not need to explicitly convert your dataframe to `float`.

In addition, note that deep copying is native in Pandas, e.g. `x_trans = x.copy(deep=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

First of I strongly recommend using the `numpy` library for those kind of mathematical operations, it is faster and outputs results in a easier way to use since both `numpy` and `pandas` are from the same project.

Now taking into account how you created your dataframe it automatically assumed your data type is integer, try to define it as float when you create the dataframe adding in the parameters `dtype = float` or better if you are using numpy package (`import numpy as np`) `dtype = np.float64`.